# Errors while exporting dump file (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle-dump

I understand this is a cliche but while doing export dump in oracle, I am getting these errors.

I have pretty much followed almost all documentation online and did these following steps:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY export_meta as '/C:/oracle/'; (where C/oracle is my local path)

GRANT READ,WRITE ON export_meta to HR 

expdp username/password DIRECTORY=export_meta
dumpfile=hr.dmp
```

But getting these errors:

ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: ad "SYS.UTIL_FILE"

Can someone please tell me if this directory needs to be created on local and any idea as to why I am getting this error?

Comment: you need to add a name and location for the logfile

Comment: do I need to specify logfile location too? I already created a logfile (manually) under C:/oracle/hr.log and provided expdp username/password DIRECTORY=export_meta
dumpfile=hr.dmp logfile='hr.log', but that even gave me errors.

Comment: actually the problem is "Create directory" does not create any directory on my local

Comment: First `/C:/oracle/` doesn't appear to be a valid path.  The leading `/` implies Unix but the `C:` implies Windows.  Unless you have a Unix box with some (odd) Windows naming conventions.  Second, that path needs to point to a directory that already exists on the database server's file system and that the operating system user running Oracle has access to.  When you say "my local path" that implies that the path is on the client machine not on the server.

Comment: so how do I create this directory? Using "/C:oracle/" did not give me any errors also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably your path '/C:/oracle/' is wrong (it starts with "/") try 'C:/oracle/' if this is just a copy/paste error then:
1) See which user started the oracle.exe process, most probably that user does not have access to write to that directory (to test this try to create the ora DIRECTORY in the $ORACLE_HOME folder, or to point to datafile folder).
2) the file hr.dmp should not exist in that directory when you start expdp

Comment: thanks! yes I removed the "/" before "C:" and voila ! it worked :)